# Android ListView and multiple threads that updates the listview

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, android-activity

I have an activity with one listview showing items. This activity has three buttons and a menu with multiple other buttons.

When i push one button, a new thread is launched, gets datas from a web service, fills the listview. Then the listview is shown.

The only problem is that each time i push one of the buttons, i launch a thread. Depending on how long it takes for the datas to be retrieved, it happens sometimes that the listview is not filled with the good datas (it the user doesn't wait for one thread to be finished and pushes another button)

First i tried to cancel the thread but it does not work (async task or with thread.interrupt)

How can i stop previous threads so that the listview will be filled with the last datas ?

Thanks for the help :)

```
// Items to be displayed in the listview
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> oItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    // Launch the thread when toggle is checked
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                LoadListView();
            }

        }
    }); 

oMenu.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                LoadListView();
                return true;
            }

        });

    private void LoadListView() {   
        new Thread(ListViewRunnable).start();
    }

    private Runnable ListViewRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (GetItems() < 1) {    
            }

            MainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        }

        private int GetItems() {
            try {
                HashMap<String, Object> oItem;

                //Get items from web services
                List<ItemFromService> oItemsFromService = GetItemsFromWebService();

                for (oItemFromService : oItemsFromService) {
                    oItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    oItem.put("ID", oItemFromService.get_iID());
                    oItem.put("Label", oItemFromService.get_sLabel());

                    oItems.add(oItem);
                }

                MainHandler.sendEmptyMessage(GOT_ITEMS);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            return 1;
        }
    }

    private Handler MainHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            if (msg.what == GOT_ITEMS) {

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you using Thread or AsyncTask or something to spawn your threads? A little sample code might help.

Comment: list some peice of code that you are using so that things become easy to understand.

Comment: I'm using threads with runnable. My thread connects to the web service, fills an array with the objects, then calls the .notifyDataSetChanged() method to refresh the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Until get the complete required data, don't use `adaptername.notifyDataSetChanged()` method So that the adapter of the `ListView` will not get Updated and the Old Data will get persisted.

Comment: Ok, but when the new thread is launched, how do i say to the old threads that they don't have to execute the notifyDataSetChanged() method ? :)

Comment: Booleans are typically used for threads to be aware of their need to keep running.. many times a thread will use while(mRunning) {..do work..}.

Comment: have you created different Async methods for all the different button click?? In our case..3 buttons so 3 async methods??

Comment: I tried to use a volatile boolean and change its value to indicate old threads that they have to stop, but the items are still displays (seems like the thread doesn't see the change of the boolean)

Comment: The main problem i think is that all the threads are filling the ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list.

But i have many buttons (maybe 20) that can launch the refresh of the listview ... so i don't really want to create 20 lists and 20 listview

Comment: In my code, the oMenu is a listview and each item is a menu item that can refresh the listview (and launches a thread)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Thread class instead of AsyncTask.  Instantiate the Thread and maintain a handle to it.  Use:

```
hThread.interrupt()
```

to send a thread an interrupt message, and inside the thread, test:

```
if (isInterrupted())
 return;
```

to leave the thread.

Comment: Ok, i will try that. I tried to put my threads in an a List and before launching a new one, i tried to interrupt the thread, but didn't check in the thread the method "isInterrupted".

When you mean "maintain a handle", it can be a an arraylist with the thread in it right ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, hThread = new Thread(...), store it in an ArrayList or whatever.  You can also use thread.isAlive() to test if the thread is currently running.  When the thread finishes, you'll want to remove it from your list.

Comment: Ok, i will try that and let you know if it's ok :)
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't seems to work. I have an arraylist of threads and one private global thread. Everytime i click on a button, i loop through the threads, call the interrupt method, clear the arraylist and call a new thread. 
In the runnable, while my objects are being retrieved from my webservice, i checked whether the thread has been interrupted.
My listview stills refresh many times with differents datas and threads don't seem to interrupt. I don't understand what i do wrong :(

Comment: `private ArrayList<Thread> oThreads;`
`private Thread oAnnonceThread;`

Comment: `for(Thread t : oThreads)
      {
       t.interrupt();
      }
      
      oThreads.clear();`